# Cant install php-zip on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, php7

I'm trying to install **php7.0-zip** on my server so I can make use of it in a PHP script, but I get a big error:

```
sudo apt-get install php-zip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libzip4 php7.0 php7.0-cgi php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-curl php7.0-fpm php7.0-gd php7.0-imap php7.0-intl php7.0-json php7.0-ldap php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache php7.0-pspell php7.0-readline php7.0-soap
  php7.0-xml php7.0-zip
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libzip4 php-zip php7.0-zip
The following packages will be upgraded:
  php7.0 php7.0-cgi php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-curl php7.0-fpm php7.0-gd php7.0-imap php7.0-intl php7.0-json php7.0-ldap php7.0-mbstring php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache php7.0-pspell php7.0-readline php7.0-soap
  php7.0-xml
19 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 128 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,865 kB/5,903 kB of archives.
After this operation, 242 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 php7.0-soap amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:2 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 php7.0-mcrypt amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:3 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 php7.0-mbstring amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:4 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 php7.0-intl amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:5 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 php7.0-imap amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:6 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-json amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:7 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-opcache amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:8 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-readline amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:9 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-cli amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:10 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 php7.0-fpm amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:11 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-xml amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:12 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-pspell amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:13 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-mysql amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:14 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-ldap amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:15 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-gd amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:16 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-curl amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:17 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-cgi amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Ign:18 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 php7.0 all 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Err:19 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 php7.0-common amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:20 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 php7.0-zip amd64 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
Err:18 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 php7.0 all 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php7.0/php7.0-soap_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php7.0/php7.0-mcrypt_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php7.0/php7.0-mbstring_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php7.0/php7.0-intl_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php7.0/php7.0-imap_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-json_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-opcache_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-readline_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-cli_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php7.0/php7.0-fpm_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-xml_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-pspell_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-mysql_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-ldap_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-gd_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-curl_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-cgi_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-common_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php7.0/php7.0-zip_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

What am I missing? Will **--fix-missing** work? Or just cause it to install without checking dependencies etc?

Server details are:

PHP 7
Ubuntu 6.04

Please let me know if you need any other details (and where to find them :))

Comment: did you run `apt-get update` first?

Comment: @Mike - ah man, I can't believe that was it! Installed perfectly that time. Not sure if I should just close this, or leave it open so other muppets like myself get a nudge in the right direction? ;)

Comment: I added an answer to help others out in case they don't see the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you run `apt-get update` to make sure the meta-data is in sync with the repos you have installed

Comment: thanks. I always assumed that `apt-get update` was just for when you added new repos to the system. I didn't realise that stuff changes even on the current one. Good to know for the future!